# hg equivalent of svn info

Tags: mercurial

I'm switching from svn to hg.  Each of my separate projects is in it's own subdirectory.  In my svn projects I was calculating the integer version no. of a project by running svn info from a Makefile.  Is there an hg equivalent for this, that would let me know the version # of each project in it's own subdirectory?  I've looked at hg summary, but that just seems to give the version # of the whole repository, not the directory the command is run in.

TY,
Fred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
hg id
```

or if you really want to get fancy:

```
hg log --template '{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}-{node}' -r .
```

which, if you're tagging releases gets you something like this:

```
1.0.1-10-6746879deadbeef05
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a single command. The previous answers focused on displaying the status of the repo tip. Add

```
hg paths
```

for repo's URL.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try,

```
hg log -r .
```

for a better output.